# How often does Amazon update its product Image URLs?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am designing a web app that use Amazon product apis to retrieve books info. I am storing images' url and other info for faster retrieval. But, I don't know how often Amazon updates/invalidate its images's urls.

Comment: You are probably better off asking them.

Comment: They will however tell you that storing the data more than 24 hours is in violation of the licensing agreement.

Comment: See section 4 paragraph (n) https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are ways to get the image just using the ASIN. You don't have to cache. Here is an example URL.

http://images.amazon.com/images/P/ASIN.01.MZZZZZZ.jpg

Just replace ASIN for the product. For more information about images, take a look at http://aaugh.com/imageabuse.html

Comment: Works for me using the url:

http://ec2.images-amazon.com/images/P/ASIN.01._SCLZZZZZZZ_.jpg

Answer (score 2):

How often these images change is not up to Amazon but depends entirely on the publishers.

I work for a publishing house and I can tell you from personal experience that a book cover can change quite frequently before going into print. Once it's available as physical product though (i.e. no more pre-order), it will remain the same until the next edition is published.

Comment: You are talking about Books in general and I am agreeing with you over that. However, my concern is Images urls, because that's totally depends upon Amazon's internal architecture of handling Images.

Comment: @GagandeepSingh I did use some old URLs (>4 weeks) in a project once and they stll worked. However, I wouldn't put it past Amazon to change URLs deliberately from time to time.